# How to show that popular matching is a special case of prioritized popular matching when priority is given by a random generator.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

For one-sided preference-based matching in a bipartite graph, we have popular matching and prioritized popular matching. One can show that popular matching is a special case of prioritized popular matching by restricting priority P=1 for each agent in prioritized matching. But what if a random number generator decides the priority of each agent? Then I can not use the above argument. How can I show that popular matching is a restricted case of this random prioritized matching?

Comment: What makes you think that it is?

Comment: Well, I was wondering that it is not impossible that the random number generator gives equal priority to each agent and in that case the problem becomes a normal popular matching problem.